# Oracle Apex 22.21 - Chart Page - Bar Type - How to return a range of date values based on user input

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a table `ORDERS` which contains column `ORDER_DATE`. I have created a **Chart** as a **Bar** type.

[image]

Right now, the chart returns all the orders because I did not specify a `Maximum Rows`. The date on the x-axis and the number of orders on the y-axis.

[image]

How can I add a form for the user to select a range of dates and return only the values for those dates?

Example:

[image]

Doesn't necessarily have to be a calendar. A dropdown is fine as well. Or even a 'text' input since that is the easiest way.. I just need to know how to go about creating this feature. Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a page item as date picker or some other plugin you already have to let users select a date or date range. (make sure that when user selects a date, the page item value is set by using a dynamic action or by a setting that your plugin has (set item value after selection kind of setting) )
Then create a new view with the source of your ORDERS table but it should have a where statement as it filters records by your page item such as:

```
select count(1)
from ORDERS
where order_date between :P1_DATE_FROM and :P1_DATE_TO
```

Set the source of the chart to this new view.
After user sets a value, refresh the chart by a dynamic action if it is not refreshed automatically.

In summary, the idea is to make your chart's source filtered by page items that users can change. Then refreshing the chart so that the new page item values are effective.

Comment: Hi Cengiz, thank you for guiding me in the right direction.  I have a follow up question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75257515/oracle-apex-22-21-chart-page-bar-type-datepicker Your help is appreciated. Thank you.