# Oracle Apex 22.21 - Chart Page - Bar Type - Datepicker

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a table `ORDERS` which contains column `ORDER_DATE`. I have created a **Chart** as a **Bar type**. I want the chart to show the amount of orders in a given date or range.

[image]

I'm following this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBIwBq1F4pE) which shows how to create a datepicker that returns a range in a **Report**. I'm trying to replicate this in a chart.

[image]

**What I've done so far**

- Created **datepicker** items `P5_DATE_FROM` and `P5_DATE_TO`
- Changed the **Series** **Source Type** to **SQL Query**

```
select ORDER_ID,
       ORDER_NUMBER,
       TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS ORDERDATE,
       STORE_ID,
       FULL_NAME,
       EMAIL,
       CITY,
       STATE,
       ZIP_CODE,
       CREDIT_CARD,
       ORDER_ITEMS,
       APEX$SYNC_STEP_STATIC_ID,
       APEX$ROW_SYNC_TIMESTAMP
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') between :P5_DATE_FROM and :P5_DATE_TO
```

- **Source** Page Items to Submit added `P5_DATE_FROM,P5_DATE_TO`

I basically followed the exact steps of the video. However, since the video is for a report and mine is for a chart, the chart isn't actually returning any data.

I think this is because for charts there are additional fields I need to configure. I noticed the video didn't cover **Column Mapping** and I'm a bit confused to what to enter here.

[image]

[image]

**----------------UPDATE-------------**

I've followed Koen's instructions from his answer. It seems like to `TO_CHAR` function was causing the error. I've updated the SQL Query to below:

```
select ORDER_ID,
       ORDER_NUMBER,
       ORDER_DATE,
       STORE_ID,
       FULL_NAME,
       EMAIL,
       CITY,
       STATE,
       ZIP_CODE,
       CREDIT_CARD,
       ORDER_ITEMS,
       APEX$SYNC_STEP_STATIC_ID,
       APEX$ROW_SYNC_TIMESTAMP
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_FROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_TO,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

However, on the **Page Designer** I cannot **save and run page** until I select **Column Mapping** - **Label** and **Value**. I've set the **Label** as `ORDER_DATE` but I am unsure of what to select for the **Value**.

Setting the **Value** to `ORDER_DATE` shows an error `Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for CHART Count Orders by Date.`

[image]

[image]

and selecting any other **Value** such as `ORDER_NUMBER` or `ZIP_CODE` populates the chart with the actual integer value of the column (ex: `ZIP_CODE` returns a chart of x-axis: date, y-axis: actual zip code numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 possible issues.

1. You submit P5_DATE_FROM and P5_DATE_TO but the source has P1_DATE_FROM and P1_DATE_TO - not sure that is a typo but it should all be the same...
2. The where clause is wrong. This

```
 from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY') between :P1_DATE_FROM and :P1_DATE_TO
```

should be

```
 from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P1_DATE_FROM,'MM-DD-YYYY') and TO_DATE(:P1_DATE_TO,'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Reason: the column `orders_local.order_date` is of datatype DATE. If you convert it to a string using `TO_CHAR` then it will be a string comparison, not a date comparison.
Note that bind variables P1_DATE_FROM and P1_DATE_TO are strings - they're defined in the DOM on the html page and that has no concept of oracle datatypes so everything is just a string. If they're used as such in a date comparison, you're relying on implicit conversion by the database. It's safer to do explicit conversion using the `TO_DATE` function.

--UPDATE--

Your question starts with "I want the chart to show the amount of orders in a given date or range.". Well... there is your answer. The "Value" is the amount of orders on each day. Update your source query to include a count of the orders and group by day. Then make your value attribute the column that has the count.

Comment: Hi Koen, thank you for putting me in the right track. Issue #1 per your answer was indeed a typo.. but it wasn't actually the problem because I changed it prior. It was due to the `TO_CHAR` function. I now have another question. Please see my updated question, Thank you.

Comment: Pls don't post followup questions within an existing question in the future. It (1) makes the forum thread unusable for users looking for answers and (2) is not seen by any other community members wanting to answer - only I can see the notification.

Comment: Hi Koen, appreciate your help on this. I've updated the question in another post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267173/oracle-apex-22-21-chart-page-bar-type-datepicker-how-to-update-the-sourc Thank you.

Comment: Thanks ! I made another update, I just now noticed that there was an error in that where clause I suggested. It is correct now.