# Oracle Apex 22.21 - Chart Page - Bar Type - Datepicker - How to update the source query to include a count and group by day

Tags: oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75257515/oracle-apex-22-21-chart-page-bar-type-datepicker/75258082?noredirect=1#comment132814721_75258082)

I want a bar chart to show the amount of orders in a given date or range. Koen's updated answer shows:

**'The "Value" is the amount of orders on each day. Update your source query to include a count of the orders and group by day. Then make your value attribute the column that has the count.'**

**How would I go about doing this?**

Summary: I have a table `ORDERS` which contains column `ORDER_DATE`. I have created a **Chart** as a **Bar type**. I want the chart to show the amount of orders in a given date or range.

[image]

I'm following this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBIwBq1F4pE) which shows how to create a datepicker that returns a range in a **Report**. I'm trying to replicate this in a chart.

**What I've done so far**

- Created **datepicker** items `P5_DATE_FROM` and `P5_DATE_TO`
- Changed the **Series** **Source Type** to **SQL Query**

```
select ORDER_ID,
       ORDER_NUMBER,
       ORDER_DATE,
       STORE_ID,
       FULL_NAME,
       EMAIL,
       CITY,
       STATE,
       ZIP_CODE,
       CREDIT_CARD,
       ORDER_ITEMS,
       APEX$SYNC_STEP_STATIC_ID,
       APEX$ROW_SYNC_TIMESTAMP
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_FROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_TO,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

- **Source** Page Items to Submit added `P5_DATE_FROM,P5_DATE_TO`

I basically followed the exact steps of the video.

However, on the **Page Designer** I cannot **save and run page** until I select **Column Mapping** - **Label** and **Value**. I've set the **Label** as `ORDER_DATE` but I am unsure of what to select for the **Value**.

Setting the **Value** to `ORDER_DATE` shows an error `Ajax call returned server error ORA-01403: no data found for CHART Count Orders by Date.`

[image]

[image]

and selecting any other **Value** such as `ORDER_NUMBER` or `ZIP_CODE` populates the chart with the actual integer value of the column (ex: `ZIP_CODE` returns a chart of x-axis: date, y-axis: actual zip code numbers)

**-----------UPDATE----------**

Per Koen's answer, I've updated the **Source** SQL Query to below but I am now receiving an error.

[image]

And if I copy the exact query that Koen suggested, I run into below:

[image]

I did some messing around and found if I include `APEX$SYNC_STEP_STATIC_ID` and `APEX$ROW_SYNC_TIMESTAMP` the missing expression error goes away but instead I receive the `GROUP BY` error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested) should work. Use `TRUNC` to ensure all orders on the same date are grouped (since date has a time portion, you'd have a different column for each different date time. Use ORDER_DATE as label and ORDER_COUNT as value.

```
select COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_COUNT,
       TRUNC(ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_DATE,
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_FROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_TO,'YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY TRUNC(ORDER_DATE)
```

Comment: Hi Koen, thanks for your response.  I've tried to update the SQL Query as you instructed but I'm receiving an error. Please see updated question. Thank you.

Comment: For a ```GROUP BY``` all columns that don't have an aggregate function need to be in the GROUP BY clause. You added 2 columns to the select - those need to be added to the GROUP BY as well. This is very basic SQL debugging. Don't be afraid to google and test :)

Comment: Hi Koen, thank you very much. This works as expected now. Sorry I don't know why I didn't think of that.. I actually have another follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75283658/oracle-apex-22-21-chart-page-bar-type-datepicker-how-to-remove-x-axis-da Thank you!