# Oracle Apex 22.21 - Chart Page - Bar Type - Datepicker - How to remove X-axis date showing time

Tags: oracle-apex

This question is a follow up to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75267173/oracle-apex-22-21-chart-page-bar-type-datepicker-how-to-update-the-sourc)

I want a bar chart to show the amount of orders in a given date or range. Everything works as expected. However, the x-axis date labels shows a date time value. I want this to show as just a date value as MM-DD-YYYY.

[image]
x-axis date labels shows a date time value
[image]

**How can I change the x-axis date labels to show as a date value as MM-DD-YYYY without the time value**

*Chart **Series** Page Designer*

[image]

*Chart **Series** Source SQL Query*

```
select COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_COUNT,
       TRUNC(ORDER_DATE) AS ORDER_DATE
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_FROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_TO,'YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY TRUNC(ORDER_DATE)
```

FYI: The `ORDER_DATE` column is saved as a `DATE` type formatted as YYYY-MM-DD. I don't save the time at all.

*X-axis Page Designer*

[image]

I did try changing the X-axis **Value** -> **Format** to `Date - Short` but that didn't change anything.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply a format mask to your date column:

```
select COUNT(ORDER_ID) AS ORDER_COUNT,
       TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY') AS ORDER_DATE
  from ORDERS_LOCAL
 where ORDER_DATE between TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_FROM,'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(:P5_DATE_TO,'YYYY-MM-DD')
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')
```

Now the trunc is no longer needed since the time portion is cut off from all dates. Note that you might need add a column with TRUNC(ORDER_DATE) anyways to the query and order by that column. Reason is that `TO_CHAR(ORDER_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY')` is a string so the order will be alphabetically and not by date.

Comment: Koen, thank you so much for your help. You are a lifesaver.. I'm so glad that an Apex expert is active on SO and is willing to help. Thank you.